# php code not executing inside do while() loop in php 5.5 wordpress 4.8

Tags: php, wordpress, php-5.5

This is the function related to DB Upgrade of wordpress plugin.
Code inside 'do' is not getting executed.
This file is used to make alterations in plugin tables.
Can someone help me with the issue ?

php version is - 5.5 , wordpress - 4.8

```
 public function upgrade($version)
 {
    @set_time_limit(300);

    if ($version === false || ((int)$version) > WpProQuiz_Helper_DbUpgrade::WPPROQUIZ_DB_VERSION) {
        $this->install();

        return WpProQuiz_Helper_DbUpgrade::WPPROQUIZ_DB_VERSION;
    }

    $version = (int)$version;

    if ($version === WpProQuiz_Helper_DbUpgrade::WPPROQUIZ_DB_VERSION) {
        return WpProQuiz_Helper_DbUpgrade::WPPROQUIZ_DB_VERSION;
    }

    do {
        $f = 'upgradeDbV' . $version;

        if (method_exists($this, $f)) {
            $version = $this->$f();
        } else {
            die("WpProQuiz upgrade error");
        }
    } while ($version < WpProQuiz_Helper_DbUpgrade::WPPROQUIZ_DB_VERSION);

    return WpProQuiz_Helper_DbUpgrade::WPPROQUIZ_DB_VERSION;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is returning before it gets to the do statement due to some of the other conditional statements before it? But hard to know what those are doing with all the values set somewhere else.

Comment: I agree with @C Miller. Are you sure `$version` and `WPPROQUIZ_DB_VERSION` are what you expect them to be? This is one of the cases where something like [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) and a good IDE can be a huge time saver.